# Python Vertical Array Slicing

Tags: python

Can anyone show me how to slice the structure below:

```
[[1, A], [2, B], [3,C]]
```

Into two separate lists:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[A, B, C]
```

I can obviously do this using code, but wondered if Python was able to do it natively?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
my_list = [[1, A], [2, B], [3, C]]
a, b = zip(*my_list)
```

Note that `a` and `b` will end up being tuples.

Comment: Thank you Sven! This is perfect.